# Drupal 8 Display True/False instead 0/1 on checkbox value in ConfigFormBase

Tags: forms, 8, configuration

By default the boolean fields' value displayed as 0/1 when user filled the checkbox field under custom configuration form. Need to render True/False instead of 0/1.

```
$form['newfield'][$id]['required'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox', 
  '#default_value' => ($config[$id]['required'] ? $config[$id]['required'] : $field['required_disabled']), 
  '#disabled' => $field['required_disabled'], 
);

public function submitForm(array & $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
    $config = $this - > config($this - > configId);
    $fields = static::getFields();
    $values = $form_state - > getValues();
    $values = $values['newfield'];
    foreach($values as $key => $field) {
        $config_values[$key] = array('visible' => $field['visible'], 'required' => $field['required'], );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In drupal8, you can easily handle this from "Manage Display" of your content type.

> Go to /admin/structure/types/manage/article/display
>   Select your "view_mode". Ex- Default.

[image]

> Go to the boolean field and click on its settings icon which is placed at atmost right side of the field.
>   Change the output format to "True/False".

[image]

Hope, this works for you.

Comment: Its a custom form.